# i have a problem when launching my Anaconda Navigator

Tags: windows, anaconda

Anaconda Navigator can't launch

After installing, when I tried to launch it, Anaconda Navigator didn't launch at all, even after I checked it didn't even appear in the task manager. I've tried various methods on the internet, but it still doesn't work. Idk what's wrong with my laptop. What do I have to do.

Just for information, I am using windows 11, and after i installed the anaconda, there's no error message.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://superuser.com